# How can i run db.currentOp() from php against a specific mongodb secondary in a replicaset?

Tags: php, mongodb, replicaset

I am trying to run the `db.currentOp()` command against different members of a mongodb  ReplicaSet to see their currently running queries.

The only one I get data from is the master, all the secondaries respond with:

```
array(3) {
  'errmsg' =>
  string(10) "not master"
  'note' =>
  string(16) "from execCommand"
  'ok' =>
  double(0)
}
```

Test-Code:

```
<?php

$servers = array();
$servers['primary'] = new MongoClient('mongodb://primary:27017');
$servers['secondary1'] = new MongoClient('mongodb://secondary1:27017');
$servers['secondary2'] = new MongoClient('mongodb://secondary2:27017');

foreach ($servers as $name => $client) {
    echo $name . ':' . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
    /* @var $client \MongoClient */
    $admin = $client->selectDB('admin');
    var_dump($admin->execute('db.currentOp()'));
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Using the Mongo shell and connecting to a secondary i can execute `db.currentOP()` in the Shell without a Problem.

Using RoboMongo ( http://robomongo.org/ ) and connecting to a secondary i can execute `db.currentOP()` in the Shell without a Problem.

Using MongoVue ( http://www.mongovue.com/ ) and connecting to a secondary i can see the running queries on the server-page.

So am i doing something wrong or is it not supported to execute this command against a secondary with php ?

Because it seems in other languages it is possible to get the data from a secondary.

I would really appreciate any tip to get this running from php somehow.

***Test-Environments***

**MongoDB Server:** 2.2.2 ( ReplicaSet with 1 Primary, 2 Secondaries)

**PHP:** 5.4.9 / 5.3.5

**MongoDB PHP Driver:** 1.4.4 / 1.3.0 on ubuntu 13.04 / debian

## Solution:

```
<?php

$servers = array();
$servers['primary'] = new MongoClient('mongodb://primary:27017');
$servers['secondary1'] = new MongoClient('mongodb://secondary1:27017');
$servers['secondary2'] = new MongoClient('mongodb://secondary2:27017');

foreach ($servers as $name => $client) {
    echo $name . ':' . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
    /* @var $client \MongoClient */
    $admin = $client->selectDB('admin');
    var_dump($admin->selectCollection('$cmd.sys.inprog')->findOne());
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: You want to execute the actual curentOp command not eval db.currrentOp, eval is not allowed on secondries

Comment: THX a lot, after a little more google and mongodocs crunching on commands,it lead me to the solution :)

`$admin->selectCollection('$cmd.sys.inprog')->findOne();`